# get total sum of counts of repeating key in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, data-science

basically i have dataframe like this

```
   col1           col2         col3    col4
1. 554862122    55110385224      PR    26                                    
2. 5242700637   55110385236      CO    246
3. 560297164    55110385250      CO    109
4. 5651138615   55110385266      PR    26
5. 5242699687   55110385289      CO    109
```

i convert it to dict like this

```
{554862122: {55110385224:  {'PR 26': 2})},
5242699687: {55110385289:  {'CO 109': 6}),
554862121: {55110385224:  {'PR 26': 3})}"
```

but now i want this but without loops

```
{'PR 26':[5,[554862122,55110385224],[554862121,55110385224]],
'CO 109':[6,[5242699687,55110385289]]}
```

Comment: Is the target always at nesting level 2? What did you try yourself? What result do you want exactly? A dictionary? A print output? I downvoted because the question is unclear and low effort.

Comment: OK, now that you changed the desired output, where is the single `5` coming from? (edit: ah, I got it, it's the sum of 2 and 3)

Comment: Show us what have you tried yet.

Comment: i have done this with loops but i want without loops

Comment: @timegb if you got my problem have you got any solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested loops to iterate over the sub-dicts and use `dict.setdefault` to initialize the sub-lists in your output dict:

```
d = {
    554862122: {55110385224:  {'PR 26': 2}},
    5242699687: {55110385289:  {'CO 109': 6}},
    554862121: {55110385224:  {'PR 26': 3}}
}
o = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    for l, w in v.items():
        for m, x in w.items():
            o[m][0] = o.setdefault(m, [0])[0] + x
            o[m].append([k, l])
print(o)
```

This outputs:

```
{'PR 26': [5, [554862122, 55110385224], [554862121, 55110385224]], 'CO 109': [6, [5242699687, 55110385289]]}
```

Comment: can i do this without loop

Comment: No. There is no way this can be done without loops because of how your dicts are nested. And why would you not want a loop?

Comment: because i have a lot of data and i take lot of time

Comment: You should use a better data structure for your input to begin with then. As it is, you simply have to iterate over all the dict items and the sub-dict items to get to the inner values.

Comment: If all your sub-dicts have only one item, you should flatten them all first. Make it a list of tuples, e.g. `[(554862122, 55110385224, 'PR 26', 2), (5242699687, 55110385289, 'CO 109', 6), ...]`.